# Circular contour plotting with different radius in python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour

I have X and Y coordinates of the data point and for corresponding (x,y) coordinates i have some values. Now i want to draw a circular contour at each (x,y) for that I have used https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html library to plot circle of different radius.
[image: Concentric Circle of different radius at given x,y coordinates]
but while coloring,the largest circle color is taking over the all smaller circle.
[image: Smallest Circle]
[image: After adding color to largest circle]
Here is the the code for reference.

```
%matplotlib qt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from numpy import linspace
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
locs=pd.read_excel(r"location of coordinates")
x=locs.iloc[:,1].values
y=locs.iloc[:,2].values

i=0
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
while i<len(x):
    temp=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.1 ,color='y') 
    a.append(temp)
    temp1=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.2 ,fill = False) 
    b.append(temp1)
    temp2=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.3 ,color='g') 
    c.append(temp2)
    i+=1
i=0
figure, axes = plt.subplots() 
while i<len(x): 
    axes.add_artist( a[i] ) 
    axes.add_artist( b[i] ) 
    axes.add_artist( c[i] ) 
    plt.title( 'Colored Circle' ) 

    plt.xlim(-3,3.2)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(-3,3.2,0.2))
    plt.ylim(-0.01,1.1)
    plt.yticks(np.arange(-0.1,1.1,0.1))
    i=i+1

plt.scatter(x,y,marker='X',c='r',s=500)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I am trying to have contour with different color. Also further i will add plt.colorbar according to which "Z" will be having some values and we will be using colors from colorbar to have colors in the circle.

Comment: Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: @itprorh66 Sorry for not writing the question will full details, i have edited the question with codes and outputs.

Answer (score 1):

You only have a `fill=False` in one of your calls to `plt.Circle`. So your first option is to add a `fill=False` to the other circles.

If you want to keep them filled, you need to make sure that the circles have an increasing `zorder` with decreasing radius.

```
while i<len(x):
    temp=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.1 ,color='y', zorder=3) 
    a.append(temp)
    temp1=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.2 ,fill = False, zorder=2) 
    b.append(temp1)
    temp2=plt.Circle(( x[i] , y[i] ), 0.3 ,color='g', zorder=1) 
    c.append(temp2)
    i+=1
```

Alternatively, if you plot the smallest circle last, it will be plotted on top of the larger circles:

```
while i<len(x): 
    axes.add_artist( c[i] ) 
    axes.add_artist( b[i] ) 
    axes.add_artist( a[i] )
```

Comment: Ordering of circle helps here, thanks a lot. I didn't thought about this.

Comment: can i ask one question if you don't mind on this topic only ?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: currently i am specifying the color of the circle, but i want them colored according to the normalized z values same as plt.color with colorbar. for this i have written a small script where color changes with a step of 0.1 but i want more precision same as plt.colorbar for that i have to repeat the same script again and again with color name, is there anyway i can use plt.color and plt.colorbar here ?

Comment: THhs is the script which i am using for coloring:                                                            `colour_coding=['lightpink','pink','crimson','palevioletred','deeppink','fuchsia','mediumorchid','indigo','orange','tomato',
               'red']

def color_code(value):
    if value>=0 and value<=0.1:
        return 1
    elif value>0.1 and value<=0.2:
        return 2;
    elif value>0.2 and value<=0.3:
        return 3;
    elif value>0.3 and value<=0.4:
        return 4; `  goes upto ten, and in color i am just calling this function to check values.

Comment: It seems to me like you are trying to re-invent the `contour` functionality in matplotlib. [Docs here.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contour_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-contour-demo-py) Maybe that would be a better starting point for what you are trying to accomplish? It would require a densely sampled list of (x, y, z) values but I would assume you either have those already or could easily obtain them from knowing the "peaks" (as you do above).

Comment: Not reinventing but trying to build a function for my work, also ordering helps here but is there any more improvement where just coloring the particular portion, since what ordering does here is that the overlapping color is just being shown.